# Pictures randomly replaced by blue question mark

Tags: images, cache

My pictures are sometime replaced by blue question mark

On the devices that have already visited my website, some pictures are randomly replaced by blue question mark. (first time visitors usually don’t have this issue).
I talked to the hosting support and I deactivated and purged cache from everywhere but still have the issue.

Hosting company is suggesting maybe a theme cach or so. Do you have any idea? Here is a screenshot of my website http://www.melti.ma from a device that already visited it before :

https://ibb.co/0hBVCkN

I'm running lated wordpress version with Chaplin theme (up to date as well).

And it looks like it happens more on Safari. On my iPhone all pictures are fine except the logo, I can't figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: Those are broken images, 404's, the blue question mark is safari telling this to the user. Also, please upload the image to this site so it gets embedded in your post, don't upload it to another service then link to it

Comment: I was able to fix this by renaming the .htaccess in the document root. It looks like it could also be compatibility issues with plugins/themes so you can always try and deactivate plugins one at a time to see if it resolves the issue.